Cannot import name XGBRegressor from xgboost (unknown location)
xgboost error
unable to import XGBRegressor
I have created an env on vscode to implement an end to end pipeline for a machine learning project. most of my code has been saved in github. I used a requirements.txt file to install all the python packages. every other packages work except for xgboost

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
